# Dialog vs. PopupMenu

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

Is there anything that a Dialog/PopupMenu can achieve that the other cannot? I have not been able to find any clear answers as to which is better in which situations and why. It would seem that either can be manipulated to achieve the exact same purposes as the other.

So is it ever necessary to use one over the other? Which is generally better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog can be used to display some alert or information, take some input from user. 
PopupMenu (ContextMenu) can be used for user navigation kind of activities

Comment: Popup Menus are like Context Menus. Context Menus are being called / open by pressing some specific buttons (Like menu hardware buttons or top corner context menu button ) and popup menus is something which app pops up pragmatically when user press a button.